# Change View Alpha on Pan Gesture or Dragging

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I want to a UIView to drag to bottom of the screen on Pan Gesture but also the view alpha should scale down to "zero", when it reaches to the bottom of the screen.

And vise versa, when I will drag the view upwards then the UIView alpha should scale down to "1"

But the problem is that **the view's alpha is scaling down to "Zero"** on panning half of the screen or sometimes when I drag the view slower.
Initially I have made the UIView background color to Black.

I need to scale down the alpha of the view gradually , any idea or suggestion will be helpful.

```
  UIPanGestureRecognizer * panner = nil;
    panner = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:panner ];
    [panner setDelegate:self];
    [panner release];


    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
    self.dimmer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [self.dimmer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:dimmer];



     -(IBAction) handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) sender {

      static CGPoint lastPosition = {0}; 
      CGPoint nowPosition; float alpha = 0.0;
      float new_alpha = 0.0;

        nowPosition = [sender translationInView: [self view]];
         alpha = [dimmer alpha] -0.0037;
         dimmer.alpha -=alpha;
    }
```

Comment: Please describe what does not work about your attempt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would look at the point on the screen you are currently at inside your `handlePanGesture:` find the percentage you are at on the view `CGFloat percentage = nowPosition.y/self.view.frame.size.height;` then set the alpha to that `dimmer.alpha = 1.0 - percentage;`. This way no matter where you are moving, you are setting the alpha to how close to the bottom you are.

Answer (score -1):

You aren't scaling relative to your gesture; you're setting `dimmer.alpha = 0.0037` every time `handlePanGesture:` executes, regardless of pan direction or distance.

```
-(IBAction) handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) sender {
  static CGPoint lastPosition = {0}; 
  CGPoint nowPosition;
  float alpha = 0.0;
  float new_alpha = 0.0; // Unused!!

  nowPosition = [sender translationInView: [self view]]; // Unused!!
  alpha = [dimmer alpha] - 0.0037;
  dimmer.alpha -= alpha; // === dimmer.alpha = dimmer.alpha - (dimmer.alpha - 0.0037)
                         // === dimmer.alpha = 0.0037 !!!
}
```

A better implementation might look something like this:

```
-(IBAction) handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) sender {
  CGPoint nowPosition = [sender translationInView: [self view]];
  CGFloat alpha = dimmer.alpha - ([sender translationInView: [self view]].y)/320.0;
  dimmer.alpha = MAX(0, MIN(1, alpha));
}
```

Comment: `CGFloat alpha = dimmer.alpha - ([sender translationInView: [self view]].y)/320.0;
  dimmer.alpha = MAX(0, MIN(1, alpha));`   --- this code will work only when the view will dragged downwards but** what about when dragged upwards to alpha scale "1.0".**

Comment: It was just an example.

Comment: Does it mean when I Will drag the view upwards then this code or logic will be same : 
 
 
CGFloat alpha = dimmer.alpha - ([sender translationInView: [self view]].y)/320.0; dimmer.alpha = MAX(0, MIN(1, alpha));

Comment: The result from `translationInView` will give you positive numbers in one direction and negative numbers in the other.